# How to reduce the width of lines in black and white images and make them thinner and smoother

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, mathematical-morphology

I have a set of black and white images as shown below like Figure 1 and I want to have them with much smaller lines like Figure 2, even though no lines are missing as much as possible. I also tried morphological methods and algorithms like Canny with Python, but I did not get the result I wanted.

[image] Figure 1

[image] Figure 2

Comment: Be careful thought, the first image is __not__ black and white !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for skeletonization, see `skimage.skeletonize`, example [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html) :

```
import skimage.morphology
import skimage.io
import skimage.util
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = skimage.io.imread('shoes.png')
image = skimage.util.invert(img)
image = image >125
skel = skimage.morphology.skeletonize(image)

plt.imshow(skel)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I tried this too. skeletonize removes many lines and loses its original shape.

Comment: I updated my answer with the output on your image, tell me if this does what you intended to

Comment: I had previously used the imutils.skeletonize which had a problem. The question with skimage was solved. Thanks